# How to ignore a file already committed on GIT repository in Eclipse using EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, ignore

I try to ignore a committed ".project" file on Eclipse EGit, without deleting it from my Eclipse project nor the repo.

I have this need :

- the ".project" file of my Eclipse project must be committed at least
  at the begining of the project, so that my co-workers can pull it
  when they will "build" their Eclipse workplace
- this file could be modified by any of us, but should not be pushed on GIT repo
- this file must stay on GIT repo all the time, because a co-worker could have to get back the project at any time
- we are working on Windows, so using command-line is a bit off-subject : I seek for help on Eclipse EGit

We are migrating from SVN to GIT : on SVN, we did not had this kind of problem, because we **could** *not commit* some files. On GIT, it seems that we have to commit everything we modify so that we do not have conflicts.

Can anybody help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: As documented in MANY other SO question/answers, it is not possible to have a file in the repo but "ignore"/not track changes to that file.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger This might be true for the command line Git, but the question is about EGit.

Comment: @howlger The eclipse extensions don't change how file tracking fundamentally works in git.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger There are no Git _eclipse extensions_. EGit is the Git integration for the Eclipse IDE which is based on Eclipse JGit, a pure Java Git _implementation_. EGit does not require the installation of the command line Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Right-click** the file and choose ***Team > Advanced > Assume Unchanged***.

See [Eclipse Help - EGit Documentation - EGit User Guide - Reference](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/User_Guide/Reference.html):

> Resources can be flagged "assume unchanged". This means that Git stops
>   checking the working tree files for possible modifications, so you
>   need to manually unset the bit to tell Git when you change the working
>   tree file. This setting can be switched on with the menu action
>   *Team > Assume unchanged* and switched back with the menu action *Team > No Assume unchanged*.

It should be noted that each co-worker must do this once. A **server-side Git hook** could reject commits changing `.project` if a co-worker had forgotten to do so.

Comment: Doesn't meet stated requirements; that removes the file from the subsequent commit.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Could you be more specific about which of the four requirements you mean?

Comment: Thank you so much @howlger : it seems to be exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @howlger - As you're well aware, you've changed your answer since I wrote that comment.  Unfortunately your new answer also does not actually meet the user's requirements, as they'll find out once they've tried using it for a while.

Comment: @pierreonthenet - Beware, while the mechanism used by the described feature is often recommended for your stated purpose, it has problem side-effects that make it a poor solution in almost every instance.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger After I tried it, I corrected my answer (that's why SO allows to edit answers). It doesn't answer my question but does add a new one: What are they supposed to find?